# $non_lazy_ptr link error with agvtool version variables?

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker-errors, non-lazy-ptr, agvtool

I've been using `agvtool` for one of my iPhone apps on general principle, and have recently found a reason why I want to be able to check the version variable (so that I can re-copy help content into the Documents directory, if it's out of date).  The variable, `MyAppVersionNumber`, defined in MyApp_vers.c, is auto-generated during the build.  It gets generated in a .o file, and shows up in (the previous version?) of the linked app itself.  So far so good, it would seem.

So now I've declared an `extern double MyAppVersionNumber` in the `.m` file where I need to use this (and later try to use it, just in an `NSLog` statement to get started), and I try to build for the iPhone simulator, and get a link error:

```
  "_MyAppVersionNumber", referenced from:
      _MyAppVersionNumber$non_lazy_ptr in HelpViewController.o
     (maybe you meant: _MyAppVersionNumber$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, what do I need to do differently, to get this to link?

I googled for $non_lazy_ptr and agvtool, and got nothing at all, and for just $non_lazy_ptr, which gave some things, but mostly applying to libraries, which this isn't, really (is it?).  And in my diggings so far, I've yet to turn up a page about agvtool that actually talks in any detail about using the variables -- the ones I've read just casually say to declare an extern variable, which I've done.

Anyone familiar with this, and/or otherwise able to provide any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...  been doing more googling, and trying different things, and I found this:

If I put the extern statement and the reference both into `main.m`, it works fine.  Using it in my view controller class, though, fails to work...  Is there some problem with having an extern variable accessible through a class (as defined by `@interface` and `@implementation`)?

I've tried putting it inside `@interface`, which fails with `error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'extern'`, and in various other places in my `.h` and `.m` (again $non_lazy_ptr link error).

How do I get access via my class?

Comment: Note: I've found a way to solve my original problem (involving making sure my Help viewer views the latest content): Don't copy it to Documents (it's read-only, so not required).

Still, it'd be nice to know what was going on, in case I ever want this variable for other reasons.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand ur question, deleted the answer.

Comment: Heh, no worries.  Thanks for reporting back.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Since agvtool updates your plist's CFBundleVersion value, I suggest accessing the version number at run-time with:

```
NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
double myVersionNumber = [(NSString *)[infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"] doubleValue];
```